# Local Group Policy Editor Configure Automatic Update not saving changes

Tags: group-policy, automatic-updates

I'm trying to configure Automatic Updates using WSUS. Server configuration is done and when I try configure clients, some clients do not save the changes I made in Local Group Policy Editor.

Some of the clients do not save changes I made in policy even if I login as Domain Admin. My client computers are Windows Server 2019 and 2022.

I change the setting like this:

[image]

When I close the editor and re-open, the setting is reverted back to default.

[image]

Comment: Are you using SCCM (Configuration Manager) or any other tool to manage your computers?

Comment: I use Server Manager and Windows built-in tools. no 3rd party.